# Get Date From TextField with UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, uidatepicker

I have a TextField with UIDatePicker associated to it on EditingDidBegin action.

I am able to get the date from the Date Picker to show in the TextField as "Feb 12, 2015" using the following code.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
installDateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
```

I have to save this value to CoreData as NSDate?

When I use the following code to convert the TextField value back to NSDate, it does not work.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us")
var installDateTime: NSDate?

if let dateString = installDateTextField.text {
   installDateTime = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}
```

TextField text is "Feb 12, 2015". How do I convert the text to "2/12/2015" so that the dateFromSting() does not fail.

Comment: UIDatePicker has a date property that shows the current picked date. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/date)

Comment: Could not make it work with NSDateFormatter.
I created a NSDate? variable and assigned the value coming from UIDatePicker inside TextField's "EditingDidBegin" method.

Later when I have to save the data to the database, I used the value from this NSDate? variable instead of converting the value from TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, you have to modify the dateformat

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM dd, yyyy"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us")
var installDateTime: NSDate?

if let dateString = installDateTextField.text {
    installDateTime = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}
```